# A drop-in blog solution that can can show up as a subdirectory /blog

Tags: react, blog

I have a react webapp on heroku and I would like to add a blog accessible through mydomain.com/blog.

I would prefer a simple drop-in solution for writing blog articles (for non-technical users with good SEO)

Some of the research I've done/tried already:

- Wordpress.com (not sure if the blog can show up as mydomain.com/blog, also I believe it has ads and all the negatives of a platform that controls everything)
- Wordpress.org (hosted somewhere else as integration with heroku doesn't look simple at all
- Headless CMS (tried prismic, it's ok, but still adds a dependency on a different company and the integration can be quite technical).
- Keep my blog in react, and use Wordpress API to pull the blog posts using JSON ( additional hosting but more flexibility)

Any recommendations for a simple blog library, or service that I can easily integrate in /blog?

Thank you

Comment: Why does using a subdomain like blog.mydomain.com not work? Setting up a blog like that is much simpler and less error-prone.

Comment: oh it does work, I just prefer the look of /blog and for some potential seo improvements

Answer (score 0):

Please bear in mind that I work for Prismic now but used to work in different agencies, anyway, I know from experience that non-technical users tend to be quite used to WordPress (and they like it a lot), although running and maintaining a full-fledged WordPress only to use its blog API sounds a bit overkill for your needs in my opinion (while remaining 100% ok)~

I don't know if there are drop in services like Disqus but for blogging (searched a bit and found dropinblog.com, looks pricey) but I'd really suggest you consider a headless CMS for that job, there are some that you can host yourself like Strapi but again if it's just to use on a small part of your site I'd personally happily get rid of the hosting part and embrace one that runs as a service (SaaS), on that field you have Storyblok, Craft CMS, Contentful, Prismic and many others...

Hope that helped a bit~